# Receive incomplete/wrong string over TCP

Tags: c#, android, tcp

I´ve got a problem with my TCP client.
My TCP server sends a Bitmap as a String to the TCP client. At the moment there are 15 bmp per second. My Problem is, that most of them are read as "//////...." when I convert the received byte array to a string.

My TCP server code is (C#):

```
private void StreamWriter(byte[] writeMessage)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(Ip), Port);

        NetworkStream streamSender = client.GetStream();
        streamSender.Write(writeMessage, 0, writeMessage.Length);
        streamSender.Flush();
        streamSender.Close();
        client.Close();

    }

    private void sendImage()
    {

        while (send)
        {
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            mem.Close();
            mem.Dispose();
            StreamWriter(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(mem.ToArray())));
            i++;
        }
    }
```

My client code is (Android Studio):

```
class MyServerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(50000);
            while (true) {
                Socket  s = ss.accept();
                InputStream is = (s.getInputStream());
                BufferedInputStream bufferedReader = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                byte[] contents = new byte[440000];
                int bytesRead = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(contents)) != -1) {
                    message = new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);

                }
                is.close();
                bufferedReader.close();

                    if (message.equals("Connection OK!")) {
                        createIP();
                    } else {
                        createPic();
                    }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `15 bmp per second.` Waht is bmp?

Comment: @greenapps probably bitmap

Comment: @greenapps bmp is the shortcut for Bitmap, means that the server converts 15 Bitmaps to a string per second.

Comment: Can you receive one of them ok? Why starting with so many at once. I see nothing in your code that indicates a base 64 encoded image.

Comment: `message = new String(contents, 0, bytesRead); ` What are you doing with `message` ? What does it contain? A part of an image? Two images? Are you concatenating 'message's ? Pretty unclear code.

Comment: `if (message.equals("Connection OK!"))` I do not see your server sending such a string.

Comment: `bufferedReader.read(contents)`. You should not use a `Reader` to read bytes. Readers are for plain texts.

Comment: I don't know java, but I suppose that's usual problem which is posted on this site every day. TCP data might arrive in chunks, there is no concept of "message" or "fragment" (like in UDP for example). So if you sent 2000 bytes, your first iteration of `bufferedReader.read` might read, for example, 1000 bytes, then second reads 500 more bytes (overwriting `message`), then third reads 500 more (again overwriting `message`). In result - your `message` contains some random number of bytes from the end of what you sent.

Comment: @ greenapps Yes, some of them are received ok. Message contains the string received by the client. The string "Connection OK!" is given to the Streamwriter over the byte array writeMessage. What would you use instead the `Reader`?

Comment: @Evk so you would look for another possibility and don´t do it over TCP?

Comment: @PrePA - no, I would read until you receive all you expect, and not overwrite previous chunks. With current code, your can try to just use `message += new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);` instead of overwriting it (and set it to null before the `while` loop).

Comment: When I´m debbuging in the client code I always get the complete message and the image is converted. Maybe the phone is to slow?

Comment: @Evk ok thx I´ll try it

Comment: I am really not completely sure, but is it ok to call `MemoryStream.ToArray()` _after_ having called `MemoryStream.Dispose()`? I also suggest to come up with an actual Protocol in order to be able to reconstruct complete images / messages / whatever from the received bytestream.

Comment: Odd ... From the docs: "This method works when the MemoryStream is closed." (ToArray) - I really expected the exact opposite. So nevermind the first part of my above comment. Personally, I'd still use a `using` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

This is the client code now:

```
class MyServerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(50000);
            while (true) {
                Socket  s = ss.accept();
                InputStream is = (s.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
                message = total.toString();

                s.close();
                is.close();

                    if (message.equals("Connection OK!")) {
                        createIP();
                    } else {
                        createPic();
                    }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```